# how to remove two column in 20 column to select query

Tags: sql

I have 20 column in one table, i want to 18 column and remove 2 column,

mysql query is

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,..........,col18 from page;
```

this query is correct, but 18 column is so larger to written, if any query present just remove 2 column???

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not support a syntax to specify *columns to exclude*. You must do with it and continue to write explicitly all the columns you want to select. You can also `SELECT *` but it is often considered bad practices.